# Is there a way to generate gmail drafts from a contacts list located in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to know whether it is possible to generate a list of gmail drafts in bulk grabbing the data from a google spreadsheet.
I have been using the mailapp function to send emails directly from a spreadsheet but this time I am looking for a way to store the emails as drafts to send them later manually one by one.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Please adde a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a draft using GmailApp.  Here's link to the [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String))

Answer (score 0):

There is also an OAuth2 library (1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF) on GitHub [here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) if you wanted then to try with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)?

You can also look at Google Sheets add-ons like SheetLink and use a formula to draft/send an email with Gmail. ([reference](https://www.sheet.link/apps/Gmail))

```
=Gmail_CreateDraft("from","to","subject","message","options")
```